# How can I make my rigid body bullets shoot in a straight line no matter my mouse movement?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a very simple 3D game in Unity where I have this space shuttle I can move around in space around asteroids and I can shoot when pressing/holding the mouse button. I'm doing this by Instantiating a sphere at the "Emitter" transform.position and then just applying a forward Force to that bullet object.
It all works fine, but the one thing I don't like and also don't know how to fix is how the bullets keep their position when shooting and moving the mouse left-right, instead of keeping a perfectly straight line at all times.

This is how it looks when I'm shooting and moving my camera at the same time:

[Screenshot while shooting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzVrT.png)

[Here's a gif for better visualization.](https://media1.giphy.com/media/cQSlyX0oAkiejBsu2E/giphy.gif)

Right now it looks like I'm pissing lasers, which is never good. I tried making the bullet speed a lot faster, but then the bullets become harder and harder to see and it doesn't look as good.

This is the code by which I'm shooting the bullets:

```
private void Fire()
    {
        GameObject bullet = Instantiate(laserPrefab);
        GameObject bullet2 = Instantiate(laserPrefab);

        Physics.IgnoreCollision(bullet.GetComponent<Collider>(), shuttleCollider.GetComponent<Collider>());
        Physics.IgnoreCollision(bullet2.GetComponent<Collider>(), shuttleCollider.GetComponent<Collider>());

        bullet.transform.position = laserEmitter.position;
        bullet2.transform.position = laserEmitter2.position;
        /*Vector3 rotation = bullet.transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
        Vector3 rotation2 = bullet2.transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
        bullet.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotation.x, transform.eulerAngles.y, rotation.z);
        bullet2.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotation2.x, transform.eulerAngles.y, rotation2.z);*/

        bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(laserEmitter.forward * laserSpeed, ForceMode.Impulse);
        bullet2.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(laserEmitter.forward * laserSpeed, ForceMode.Impulse);

        StartCoroutine(DestroyBulletAfterTime(bullet, bulletDeathTime, bullet2));
    }
```

Don't mind the commented lines, I was just messing around trying to see if I can get it to work. The shooting behaves the same with or without those commented lines.

Comment: It does look like you're pissing lasers :)  But aren't the bullets following their actual original trajectory?  I mean you are moving your ship but the bullets remain in the direction of their original shot.  Try slowing down the fire rate (way down) and see if it looks more "logical"

Comment: Agree with the comment before: The behavior looks correct to me. Each individual bullet is following a straight line into the direction it had when it was instantiated

Comment: You know btw that you don't need that `DestroyBulletAfterTime` routine ;) you can simply use [`Destroy(bullet, bulletDeathTime);`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html) which does exactly that ;)

Comment: @jiveturkey

I mean yeah, I know the behavior is phisically correct as the bullets follow their trajectory that was set at spawn time, but I still don't like the way it looks.

So do you have any idea what I could change to get perfect straight shooting? I tried some Raycast shooting, but then I don't get to see the actual lasers being shot and moving through space.

Answer (score 3):

Of course, a projectile based system will behave and look like a projectile system.

If you want laser behavior use a LineRenderer. Raycast where your laser line should end (either laser max distance or the point of hitting an object in range).

If you don't like the "static" looks of it, change the LineRenderer Material to something that changes over time (search for shaders/ LineRenderer effects).

Comment: Thanks! I was afraid this might be the answer - ie change the shooting system almost entirely.
I was hoping that I could somehow change a few lines of code and be done with it. Cause I only had like one hour left to stay at the studio before I had to leave and didn't want to have to do something that would take more time.